# with Haskell program how to find the common characters of two strings and display them

Tags: haskell

I need to write a function to find the common characters of two strings and display these common characters .I think is trivial program but i dont know how put together the functions:with the function elem i can test if x element is in the string.With filter i can take only the common elements to show them in one string. But how to relate /compare these 2 strings.?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question. If you have the common characters in one string, isn't that exactly what you want already?

Comment: Also i am a litlle confuse if I can adjust the previous information to this.Two days ago i was  looking for how determine if one string is substring of other. Example: the string:"I am going to the school"and then i wanted to know if the string "going" was substring (true).But know i need to determinate the commoon characters in any place or order,For example if the second string is "else"has common characters(e,l,s)but it is not substring.Now i dont know the common characters (I believe the redaction was not right)actually is:to find all characters that are common to 2 strings and show them

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to find the intersection of two lists?

```
Data.List> intersect "haskell" "java"
"a"
```

Comment: Please notice, that you have to import `Data.List` by typing `import Data.List` at the top of your file before you can use `intersect`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a fold (considering the two strings li1 and li2):

```
     foldl (\xs x -> if elem x li2 then (x : xs) else xs) [] li1
```

Comment: Other than reversing the result, how is your `foldl` different from using `filter`?

Answer (score 0):

You could `filter` one string for chars being `elems` of another. And that is most simple way to go.